# Exported perl module subroutines are not available

Tags: perl, perl-module, circular-dependency

Say I have 3 perl files.

run.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Common;

validate();    # no need of Common::validate()
```

Common.pm

```
package Common;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw(import);
use Validator;

our @EXPORT = qw(validate inArray);

sub validate
{
    Validator::doSomething();
}

sub inArray
{
    print("HERE\n");
}

return 1;
```

Validator.pm

```
package Validator;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Common;

sub doSomething
{
    inArray();    # only Common::inArray() works here, why?
}

return 1;
```

When run the output is: `Undefined subroutine &Validator::inArray called at Validator.pm line 10.`

If I change

```
sub doSomething
{
    inArray();
}
```

to

```
sub doSomething
{
    Common::inArray();
}
```

then the result is expected `HERE`.

My question is why are the subroutines exported by the Common module not available in the Validator module?

I'm using perl 5.22.0.

Comment: Circular dependencies like this should be avoided. `Common` uses `Validator`, and `Validator` uses `Common`. Split up the functions in `Common` into two modules.

Comment: @tinita I am aware of the circular dependency. However my vision is that there will be many modules and they all will be using the Common module with some common functions. And some of these functions may require functionality provided by one of those modules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `Validator.pm` is loaded and processed before `@Common::EXPORT` is defined.

Some workarounds are either to

- define `@Common::EXPORT` during the "compile phase" of `Common.pm` and before `Validator.pm` is loaded

  ```
  # Common.pm
  ...
  BEGIN { our @EXPORT = qw(validate inArray) }
  use Validator;
  ...
  ```
- load `Validator.pm` during the "run phase" of `Common.pm` and after `@Common::EXPORT` is defined

  ```
  # Common.pm
  ...
  our @EXPORT = qw(validate inArray);
  require Validator;
  Validator->import;
  ...
  ```

Comment: Or just put `
our @EXPORT = qw( validate inArray )` in a `BEGIN` block before the `use Validator`